# How to parse data from NfcA tag?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare, open-nfc

I am reading NfcA tags using RFID reader described in following link.

[MF7-28](http://www.gigatms.com.tw/dl_giga/RFID%20Products/13.56MHz/Mifare/MF7_MR2/(MF7-20)%20TM951060-02.pdf)

I have connected this tag reader serially, reader is sending data when I scan the tags with the reader.

But data doesn't match with the serial ID of the tags.
Serial Id is printed on the tag and we can also read it using Android phone.

Data Got From reader : BF 96 F6 93 75 95 75 79 E5 EB F9 00

Data from Android : EC E5 86 73 FC 88 04 00 C0 8E 1E 97 45 00 17 13

Where Serial Id printed on tag is : 73 86 E5 EC , so this must be the revers of first 4 bytes in reverse order EC E5 86 73.

Can anyone please help me to decode the data from tag Reader?

or is that possible to write some code in android to get the data in the same format return by tag reader?

Following is the complete hex from Sector 1.

```
ECE58673FC880400C08E1E9745001713
140103E103E103E103E103E103E103E1
03E103E103E103E103E103E103E103E1
A0A1A2A3A4A5787788C1FFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: please comment the reason behind close mark, so I can work on it.

Comment: The data that you received over the serial interface does not match any of the format specifications in the linked datasheet. Are you sure that you properly configured the reader and the serial receiver?

Comment: Yes I have done the serial connection as per description. 
I tested 3 types of tags, next bytes are repeated.

BF xxxxxx E5 EB F9 00 in each type of tags. So these bytes must be prefix and suffix of the reader. The data shuld be 96 F6 93 75 95 75 79

Comment: @MichaelRoland, please check if this can give you a hint. Let me know if you want more specific info? I will give you all details whatever you want.